# Stop hide/show of series but grey out legend on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on Stacked Column Chart in Highcharts. I have a requirement that on click of a legend the legend should grey out as it happens by default but the series/stack should not be hidden and remain same in color.

I tried this and got the series to stop hiding by using this:

```
events: {
    legendItemClick: function () {
        return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
    }
}
```

But I am not able to grey out or disable the clicked legend.

Here is the [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ee7w6mww/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to overirde legendItemClick . Just add color and toggle thing as per your requirements.

see working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4tt89sw5/)

one with toggle functionality is [here](https://codepen.io/himanshu9419/pen/RxRqrp?editors=1000)

```
$(function () {
     var selected = null;
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {

                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault()
                  var series = $('#container').highcharts().series[0];
                  series.color = "#fbfbfbf";  $('#container').highcharts().legend.colorizeItem(series, series.visible);
                  $.each(series.data, function(i, point) {
                 point.graphic.attr({
                   fill: '#fbfbfb'
                 });
                 });
                 series.redraw();        

                            this.update({ color: '#999' }, true, false);
                            selected = this;
                            }, 
                mouseOver: function() {    
                    if(this != selected)
                    this.update({ color: '#999' }, true,false);
                }
                    }

            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: It works only for the first time. I want it to enable and disable on every click

Comment: Toggle functionality you have to figure out. Or wait for some time will implement that also.

Comment: see updated link https://codepen.io/himanshu9419/pen/RxRqrp?editors=1000 width toggle functionality. Note:- set you own color.

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting the `Highcharts.Legend.prototype.setItemEvents` core function seems to be an elegant solution.

I removed the code responsible for handling `mouseover` and `mouseout` events. Then I implemented custom behavior for the `onclick` event:

```
(function(H) {

  Highcharts.Legend.prototype.setItemEvents = function(item, legendItem, useHTML) {
    // Set the events on the item group, or in case of useHTML, the item itself (#1249)
    (useHTML ? legendItem : item.legendGroup).on('click', function(event) {
      if (item.clicked) {
        legendItem.css({
          fill: 'black'
        });
      } else {
        legendItem.css({
          fill: 'gray'
        });
      }

      item.clicked = !item.clicked;
    });
  };

})(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/kje28s4v/

**Docs reference about overwriting core functions:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts